# How do you use the mrt:natural package in an app?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have installed http://atmospherejs.com/mrt/natural by 'meteor add mrt:natural' (I am using Meteor 0.9.1). It seems to be installed ok, but the 'usage' says to simply call :

```
natural = Natural
```

This doesn't work when applied on the server or client side. I'm sure this must be so obvious as I can't see anyone else having the problem...

Yes, I am pretty new to Meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package doesn't seem to be maintained ([last update 6 Jun 2013](https://github.com/Pent/meteor-natural)). There's also no need for it to be, since it's a simple wrapper for a Npm package, which can be now loaded in a better way.

Add [npm](http://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) package to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

and then create `packages.json` file with `natural` specified as per [documentation](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm/). Then you'll be able to require `natural` with `Meteor.npmRequire('natural');`.